# Error when importing data via source() using Æ as separator in R

Tags: r, read.csv

So this is an inexplicable error for me and I would suggest it is a bug if noone has an explanation:

I have the following code to import a file into R:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(read.csv("file.csv", header=TRUE, sep = "Æ", quote = "", dec = ",", stringsAsFactors=TRUE, row.names = NULL))
```

Which works perfectly fine.
I always export the data from Access using `Æ` as separator because it is a nice character that never occurs in my files.

Now for the error:

When I create a new file *("import.r")* with the code:

```
DT <- data.table(read.csv("file.csv", header=TRUE, sep = "Æ", quote = "", dec = ",", stringsAsFactors=TRUE, row.names = NULL))
```

And use source in the original code:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(data.table)
source("import.r")
```

I get the error:

```
Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte
```

Interestingly, if I do not use `Æ` as separator but `|` it works perfectly fine when sourcing the file. So the error is apparently caused by using `Æ` as a separator (as stated in the error anyway).

But how can the same import command work just fine when called directly but return a seemingly unrelated error when called via `source()`?

EDIT:
Reading the character using different encodings returns different results:

```
> readLines(textConnection("Æ",encoding="UTF-8"))
[1] "Ã†"
> readLines(textConnection("Æ"))
[1] "Æ"
```

Setting *UTF-8* encoding in the code as James suggested in his answer oddly works and the file is imported correctly.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with encoding when sourcing?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik No. From `?source`: *By default the input is read and parsed in the current encoding of the R session.* So if I'm right if it was an encoding issue the error would also have to occur when I call the import directly, as both should be using the same encoding.

Comment: FWIW, using a US UTF-8 locale on OSX I get the "one byte" error either way, sourcing or running it directly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an encoding issue. When reading `Æ` in through a text connection with UTF-8 encoding you get 2 characters returned:

```
readLines(textConnection("Æ",encoding="UTF-8"))
[1] "Ã†"
```

Oddly however, setting UTF-8 as the encoding when sourcing allows the data to be read in correctly.

Comment: After Roman's suggestion I tried setting the encoding to different formats including UTF-8 but it still gave the same error. Did you try it with importing a file? Might be country\OS-specific issue?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I'm using Windows in the UK. I can replicate your issue and it goes away when I set the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Ok have to try tomorrow in work again probably I set the encoding wrong

Comment: I have yet to grasp all the encoding issues in R. I noticed it differs across platforms and IDEs. Sigh.

Comment: @James So I just tested it again and setting `source("import.r",encoding="UTF-8")` indeed works and R correctly imports the file. Which is really strange as your `readLines` example shows.